# Large value predictions using Physics informed neural network (PINN) for inverse problems

Tags: deep-learning

So i am stuck forever in this problem where we have to predict two variables values in an ODE equation using the given data points. The problem is everything works perfectly when the values of the variables to be predicted is very small (upto range of 10). But as soon as the values to be predicted is large (assume in 100s) it breaks. It predicts everything as 0. But the loss (data loss + PDE loss) is still very less. I tried adaptive weight method, curriculum learning, sequential learning and everything in between. Still no results. I know the landscape becomes very sophisticated at large values but i want to know the solution for it?

Comment: Can u precise the ODE you want to solve, your Neural Network architecture and loss to be minimized?